# How can I add a blank line before some data using Ruamel.yaml

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I can't seem to figure out how I can add a blank line between data using Ruamel.yaml.

Suppose I have data:

```
---
a: 1

b: 2
```

I need to add to this so that I will have:

```
---
a: 1

b: 2

c: 3
```

I understand that the blank line is implemented as a CommentToken:

```
Comment(comment=None,
  items={'data': [None, None, CommentToken(value=u'\n\n'), None], 'b': [None, None, CommentToken(value=u'\n\n'), None]})
```

What I don't know is how to manipulate that structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `Comment` object is not from the input that you give, as `data` is not a key in your mapping, that should be `a`:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_strs = [
"""\
---
a: 1

b: 2
""",
"""\
---
a: 1

b: 2

c: 3
"""]

for yaml_str in yaml_strs:
    data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
    print(data.ca)
```

gives:

```
Comment(comment=None,
  items={'a': [None, None, CommentToken(), None]})
Comment(comment=None,
  items={'a': [None, None, CommentToken(), None], 'b': [None, None, CommentToken(), None]})
```

comparing the above comments should give you an idea of what to try:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
---
a: 1

b: 2
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
data['c'] = 3
ct = data.ca.items['a'][2]
data.ca.items['b'] = [None, None, ct, None]
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: 1

b: 2

c: 3
```

The CommentToken `ct` can also be constructed from scratch:

```
ct = ruamel.yaml.tokens.CommentToken('\n\n', ruamel.yaml.error.CommentMark(0), None)
```

as is, e.g. done in `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedBase.yaml_set_start_comment()`.

The `0` parameter to `CommentMark()` is how far the comment is indented, which is not important in case of empty lines, but still needs to be provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance @Anthon.  At this point I can't try it because it looks like I need a higher version of Ruamel, and when I try to install the latest version of Ruamel on my Mac, the installation fails. I may raise a bug about that separately.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of pip/setuptools etc in your virtualenv before you install ruamel.yaml. After which version did the install stop working?